# How to make AppleScript count exactly?

Tags: macos, applescript

How do I make AppleScript count exactly?

According to AppleScript, the following equation would be true:
`89723443578920345892 / 2 = 448617217894600000000`

That, though, is not true. What can I do in order to make AppleScript actually count without rounding it afterward?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command line utility [`bc`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bc.1.html) is capable of arbitrary precision mathematics, and you can call a command line utility from AppleScript and get a value from it.

For example:

```
set myVariable to do shell script "echo \"89723443578920345892 / 2\" | bc"
```

Gives this result: `44861721789460172946`

To pass command line arguments as AppleScript variables:

```
set myNumber1 to "89723443578920345892"
set myNumber2 to "2"
set myVariable to do shell script "echo " & myNumber1 & " / " & myNumber2 & "| bc"
```

But this gets us back to the original problem, AppleScript represents large numbers as a float, so I had to pass the value as a string. So depending on where you get the very large number from, this could be problematic or a non-solution.

Comment: can I include the variable in command line counting? I need the variable to set itself to itself/2.

Comment: I've submitted an edit that includes passing the numbers from variables to the command line, but I ran into the problem of AppleScript representing the numbers as a float.